# Jena dbpedia how to use (STR(?foo) AS ?foo2)?

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

i want to avoid using substring to eliminate by example @en in my 
ontology:abstract or ontology:label, it work with sparql explorer but when i use http query in jena it dont give any result... i tried this query in android project with jena library (androjena)

```
   SELECT ?type (STR(?l) AS ?label) {
   ?type a owl:Class;
         rdfs:label  ?l .
   FILTER (LANG(?l) = "en")
}
```

once i put this in my Jena httpquery `(STR(?l) AS ?label)`it dont give any result anymore. someone can help me?

here is the part of the code that i try to manage to change to avoid use of substrings :

```
 private String entityQuery(String entity, String keyWord, String language) {

        return addPrefix("rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>") +
                addPrefix("ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>") +

                addQuery("SELECT ?name  ?desc ?thumb  WHERE {\n"
                        +"?author a ontology:" + entity + ";\n"
                        +"rdfs:label ?name;\n"
                        +"ontology:abstract ?desc.\n"
                        +"FILTER(<bif:contains>(?desc,\"'"+keyWord+"'\") && langMatches(lang(?desc), \""+language+"\") " +
                        "&& langMatches( lang(?name), \""+language+"\"))\n"
                        +"OPTIONAL { ?author ontology:thumbnail ?thumb }.\n"
                        +"}ORDER BY ?name\n");
    }

    private LinkedList<Entity> collectEntities(ResultSet results) {
        LinkedList<Entity> temp = new LinkedList<>();
    /* do stuff with the results */
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            Entity a = new Entity();
            QuerySolution row = results.next();
            if (row.getResource("thumb") != null)
            a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb").toString());
            a.setTitle(row.get("name").toString().substring(0, row.get("name").toString().indexOf("@")));
            a.setSummary(row.get("desc").toString().substring(0, row.get("desc").toString().indexOf("@")));
            temp.add(a);
        }
        return temp;
    }




    private String addPrefix(String prefix) {
        return "PREFIX " + prefix + "\n";
    }

    private String addQuery(String query) {
        return query;
    }
```

i use substring here :

```
  a.setTitle(row.get("name").toString().substring(0, row.get("name").toString().indexOf("@")));
        a.setSummary(row.get("desc").toString().substring(0, row.get("desc").toString().indexOf("@")));
```

Comment: which endpoint are you querying? do its labels have `@en` language tags? what happens if you try `FILTER(LANG(?l)="" || LANG(?l)="en")`?

Comment: @JörnHees Generally, you shouldn't use `lang(...) = ...` to check language tags (but you *should*, to check that a language tag is "".  So that should probably be `filter( langMatches(lang(?l),"en") || lang(?l) = "" )`.

Comment: "avoid using substring to eliminate by example @en" --- The "@en" you might see in a printed representation isn't part of the lexical form of the literal, so extracting a substring wouldn't remove it.  If you just want the lexical part of the literal, str(?literal) is the right way to go.  Can you show us some of the data you're actually querying?

Comment: [joshua](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor) i've added the code where i used it

Comment: @StackItEasy does the problem still exist? Do you maybe just want to replace `a.setTitle(row.get("name").toString()...` with `a.setTitle(row.get("name").asLiteral().getString())`?

Comment: @JörnHees That's a very good point about execution time (+1 for that comment).  It's not just regional codes like "en-US" and "en-GB" though.  There's also case sensitivity.  [RFC 3066](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt) says "All tags are to be treated as case insensitive; there exist conventions for capitalization of some of them, but these should not be taken to carry meaning."  So you could still have an English string, but `lang("foo"@EN) = "en"` would fail. That said, if one knows that DBpedia normalizes language tags (I don't know whether it does), it's probably OK as an optimization.

Comment: tks, and sorry for the late reply ill try it when ive more time ;) and can someone provide me the best solution to get this query run faster or give me hints on how i should doit run faster? :P